# Perl Locale warning Debian

Tags: perl, warnings, debian, locale

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_CA.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I keep getting this message.  I am running Debian on a VPS.  I've tried numerous solutions I've found through Google, none have helped. What do I do?

Comment: generate your locale using localgen.

Comment: I've ran locale-gen and have received the same results.

Comment: edit your `/etc/locale.gen`, add  `en_CA.UTF-8` . or reconfigure your locale package

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/131193/debian-ubuntu-locales-and-language-settings

Comment: Run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root.

Answer (score 42):

Try setting the locales directly this way, it worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04, just tailor the locales to your needs:

```
root@hostname:~# export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
root@hostname:~# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
root@hostname:~# export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
root@hostname:~# locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

and then:

```
root@hostname:~# dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 5):

Configuring Locales in Debian: http://people.debian.org/~schultmc/locales.html